# Truncating long formulae in titles breaks formatting in search result lists

Tags: bug, search, mathjax

When displaying search results, long titles are truncated. That's fine with me, but if the closing `$` of a formula in the title is dropped, bad things happen:

[image]

The same happens when the excerpt starts or ends in the middle of a formula.

Ending truncated formulae with `\dots $` instead of `…` should fix the issue.

<sub>I would agree that long formulae in titles are bad, but what can you do...</sub>

Comment: "What can you do", shorten them, or not apply them in the title. That's just my $.02.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha: The issue still applies if you have short formulae in long titles (and bad luck) and those can't always be avoided.

Comment: I don't know how you guys do on [cs.se], but on [so] we actively discourage the use of code in titles, for example.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha: We discourage it, too, but sometimes you have to choose between a meaninglessly generic title and one with formulae. That said, the issue applies to excerpts, and *these* are definitely supposed to contain formulae. (And, it's still a bug even for titles.)

Comment: This is still an issue, as can be seen [with that same query](http://cs.stackexchange.com/search?q=[regular-languages]++m+\neq+n).

Comment: This is still an issue on Mathematics SE.